# How is surface tension of the de-ionized water ( pure water ) decreased with the increase in the concentration of NaCl?

Tags: surface-tension

Can anyone help me with the theory of surface tension? My physics experiment is related to the surface tension and concentration of NaCl. I am confused about my Hypothesis. On the internet, I found that increasing salt concentration also increases the surface tension of the water. But in my experiment, surface tension is decreasing with the increase of NaCl. So can anyone help me with the theory behind this?

With the help of needle and water drops, I was able to calculate the value of surface tension of water for each concentration of NaCl.

Comment: If surface tension is decreasing with the addition of salt, I'd be skeptical of the purity of your salt. Perhaps from it or your lab tools, you're contaminating the water with surfactants or other substances.

Comment: De-ionized does not mean pure. Just elimination of (most) of the ionic species.